# Enqueue and TryDequeue in ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

There is a ConcurrentQueue instance and two threads that access it concurrently. One thread enqueues items continuesly (may be enqueue few items in 100 micro seconds) and other thread TryDequeue item by item and do some processing. There is a ManualResetEvent to signal the processing thread after any item enqueue (this is not quite related to this question)

In this case, is there any possibility of adding items in wrong order to the ConcurrentQueue.  I know it's thread safe but just want to make sure whether it does not mess with the order of items when enqueue and dequeue quite faster.

Comment: 'There is a ManualResetEvent to signal the processing thread after any item enqueue' :(

Comment: It's a queue!  If it could reorder entries, they would have called it ConcurrentBingoMachine, ConcurrentLottery, ConcurrentShoppingTrolley or something.  The only way things get out-of-order on producer-consumer queue pipelines is if there is more than one consumer thread.

Comment: Aparrently, there is a 'ConcurrentBag' class, so, not ConcurrentBingoMachine :((

Comment: Agree with Martin. Perhaps you can post your actual issue with relevant code!

Comment: @MartinJames : Thanks for naming suggestions for unordered queues. BTW, could you explain "The only way things get out-of-order on producer-consumer queue pipelines is if there is more than one consumer thread." ?

Comment: @Harsha - if a pipeline of producer-consumer queues, one task may require much more processing than the others, eg. there is some special processing on a video frame.  It is therefore tempting, on a multicore box, to use more than one thread, (A and B, say), at that stage of the pipeline in order to make best use of the CPUs available and reduce overall latency.  The snag is then that thread A might get a frame first but thread B might finish first, so enqueueing its frame to the next stage before A and resulting in out-of-order video.

Comment: @Harsha - another 'classic' example is IOCP servers.  'IOCP' is M$-speak for an event queue with benefits.  Typically, a pool of user threads waits on an IOCP queue for socket-completion events.  It can happen that more than one thread can process read event buffers for the same socket and so assemble files and other data 'out-of-order', despite TCP guarantees:(  Typically, each socket object will maintain a sequence-number that is copied into each buffer and incremented biefore processing, so allowing buffers to be resequenced at a later stage if found out-of-order.

Comment: @MartinJames: Thanks, post this as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is absolutely no way that the items can be out of order.

First of all, a queue by definition enforces a FIFO order: you put elements at one end and take them out at the other end. And since this is done by a single-producer-single-consumer model, it's absolutely safe.

Answer (score 2):

It's a queue! If it could reorder entries, they would have called it ConcurrentBag or something. The only way things get out-of-order on producer-consumer queue pipelines is if there is more than one consumer thread.

Comment: I think ConcurrentShoppingTrolly is a better name